# error TS1243: 'async' modifier cannot be used with 'abstract' modifier

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, abstract-class

In my project, I was using `Typescript@4.0.3` and it was working fine, but now I updated its version to latest `Typescript@4.1.3` and it is giving me a lot of errors. I am unable to find anything in documentations and not getting any Idea how to resolve this issue.

here is my code:

```
abstract class SystemValidator {

    constructor() {}

    abstract async validate(addr:Addr):Promise<[boolean, Addr[], SystemValidationErrors]>
```

}

This is giving me error:

> error TS1243: 'async' modifier cannot be used with 'abstract' modifier.

Any idea to resolve this issue?? Should I remove `aync` from here??

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes you should remove `async`.

You should not force to use `async` to the class that implements it. There are other ways to return a `Promise`, not just `async`.

### Edit:

Since it is not clear for some people why the `async` is not important. Here a couple of ways to return a promise:

```
async function iAmAsync(): Promise<boolean>{
    return false;
}

function iAmNotAsync(): Promise<boolean>{
 return new Promise(resolve => resolve(false));
}

function iAmAlsoNotAsync(): Promise<boolean>{
 return new Observable().pipe(first()).toPromise();
}

iAmAsync().then();
iAmNotAsync().then();
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsI1QQQLY7jQAUAlAFwwAKATunqiAKYA8ARuugDZPAQB8AbwBQMMTBpNkCGljjAuzANzCAvsOGIUGLLjwA5dMkKQoZSrXqNWHbrwEiJUmVghMA7tToNmxSSG4ANyYYAF5%20JwCuYOJ5RSZSUhV1YT0TElIAOmQACyYIMhU9Q2MiMyzc-MKgA)

Comment: He *should* force the class that implements it to return whatever he needs to be returned. The fact is TypeScript is limited on that one. What should happen is TypeScript must allow the async modifier with abstract if that's what the developer intends.

Comment: You said it. An interface or abstract class can require **to return whatever you want**, the `async` modifier has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Of course it does. It converts any return to a Promise and informs the user of the function a promise is guaranteed to be returned. That's JavaScript 101. The async modifier only has to do with the return and has nothing to do with anything else. If a developer wants to enforce it just for code readability and not getting forced to return new Promise() which is actually transparent and automatic with async he should be allowed to.

Comment: See the updated answer with the explanation why it should not be forced :)

Comment: **Just because you can do away with async it doesn't mean it makes the code more readable. Less is not more.** Many languages allow for redundant modifiers to be enforced in interfaces specifically to make bugs less likely and simplify refactoring after library changes (even if its only a visual help). For example, Swift allows a programmer to enforce named params for interface functions such that the caller **must** name the params when calling. I'd enforce the async modifier just for code readability (or just for consistency to ensure ctrl+F through project can use have simple keywords).

Comment: You are talking about one project **guidelines**. That is not a luxury one can have when working with a library that can be used by several big teams in one or multiple organizations, that can or not agree with what you think my friend.

Comment: Multiple teams and multiple orgs is precisely what enables advanced enforcing of function signatures to allow easy refactoring without blowing up silently in other's code ;)

Comment: You can refractor everything you want as long as the **return** of the function is what the `interface`/`abstract` function signature requires. Anyway, you are welcome to create a feature request for the Typescript team to allow `async` on `abstract`/`interface` functions. Maybe you are right and the Typescript team is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove the `async` keyword from the declaration and still use `async` in the implementation.

```
abstract class Shape {
  abstract area(): Promise<number>;
}

class Circle extends Shape {
  constructor(private radius: number) {
    super();
  }

  async area() {
    return Math.PI * Math.pow(this.radius, 2);
  }
}

(async () => {
  const circle = new Circle(5);
  console.log(await circle.area());
})();
```

If you want to know why you don't need it and why it is totally redundant, I will refer to [this explanation I found on TypeScript Github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49096#issuecomment-1126234754)

> The only two things the `async` modifier does is: 1. make a function return a promise, and 2. allow use of `await` in the implementation. Since an abstract method has no implementation and you *already* have to declare its return type as `Promise<Whatever>`, the `async` is redundant in that context.